# How to search by date range in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am new in AngularJs, I am creating a search template, select a **From** date and a **To** date, I need result of this range when I clicking the search button.

after clicking the search button the result needs to be populated,

```css
table td,
th {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="clearfix" ng-controller="tableDataCtrl">
    From : <input type="date" id="fromDate" name="fromDate"><br> To : <input type="date" id="toDate" name="toDate"><br>
    <input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search"><br>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="th in tableHeader">
            {{th}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="tr in tableData">
          <td ng-repeat="td in tr">
            {{td}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('tableDataCtrl', function tableDataCtrl($scope, $http) {
    // $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/uwz13").then(function (response) {

    $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/cl913").then(function(response) {
      // console.log(response);
      $scope.tableData = response.data.data;
      $scope.tableHeader = response.data.header;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to convert invoiceDate into date first and then compare with fromDate and toDate

Answer (score 1):

The best practice in AngularJS for what you want to do is to create a filter like this:

```
app.filter("dateRange", function() {
    return function(items, fieldName, fromDate, toDate) {
        var from = new Date(fromDate);
        var to = new Date(toDate);
        var itemsInRange = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var date = new Date(items[i][fieldName]);
            if(from <= date && date <= to)
                itemsInRange.push(items[i]);
        }
        return itemsInRange;
    };
});
```

This filter takes your data items list, field to filter by ("InvoiceDate" in your case), date range start and end. It returns only those items which fall between the date range boundaries.

It can be used in HTML directly (refreshes whenever parameters change):

```
<tr ng-repeat="tr in tableData | dateRange: 'InvoiceDate':fromDate:toDate">
```

Or you can use it programmatically in JavaScript (refreshes on demand):

```
$filter('dateRange')($scope.tableData, 'InvoiceDate', fromDate, toDate);
```

Checkout this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oygnegba/) which demonstrates the solution above.